# Array of object not assigning value through spread operator correctly

Tags: javascript, arrays, object

I am using spread operator but my operation is not working correctly.

Here is my code and problem.

I declare a array of object.

`let obj = [{id:1,name:"a"},{id:2,name:"b"}]`
then i am copying this to another variable. like this.

`let newObj = {...obj}`

now after copying what i am getting in newObj is object of array. means i can access `newObj[0]` or `newObj[1]` but i can not use for loop. I can not access `newObj.length`. how to fix this problem. can anybody please suggest that.

Comment: If you want to shallow clone an array, use `slice`. If you want to deep clone it, use `JSON.stringify` / `parse` or something recursive. It's *really weird* to try to turn an array into a non-array object - best to avoid that unless there's no other way

Comment: Then in that case when to use spread operator.

Comment: Use object spread when you want to create a new *object*. Use array spread when you want to create a new array.

Comment: oh. noted, thanjs